# How can save and print Arraylist to a file?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Book implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String name;
private String author;

public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}

public Book(String name, String author) {
    this.name = name;
    this.author = author;
}

public void disPlay() {
    System.out.print("Book name : " + name);
    System.out.println("\tAuthor name : " + author);
}
}

public class Print {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    writeList();
    List<Book> list = readList();
    for (Book obj : list)
        System.out.println(obj);
}

public static List<Book> readList() throws Exception {
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("object.dat"));
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Book> readObject = (List<Book>) in.readObject();
    in.close();
    return readList();
}

public static void writeList() throws Exception {
    List<Book> list = new ArrayList<>();
    ObjectOutputStream out = null;
    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        System.out.print("Enter the book, author name : ");
        String name = scan.next();
        String author = scan.next();
        list.add(new Book(name, author));
        System.out.print("If you want to save to the list -1, if you don't want, enter 1 : ");
        int choice = scan.nextInt();
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("object.dat"));
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        System.out.print("Save the list to a file");
    }
}
}
```

I try to get the ArrayList object stored in the file (object.dat), save the Book object in the ArrayList, and then save the ArrayList where the Book object is stored in the file before the end of the program.

The result I want is,
[Results When Program First Runs]

```
There are no saved values

Enter the book, author name : Harrypotter jkrowling
If you want to save to the list -1, if you don't want, enter 1 : -1
Save the list to a file
```

and,
[Results on Second and Later]

```
---Outputs the value stored in the file name---
Book name : Harrypotter
Author name : jkrowling

Enter the book, author name : Twilight StephenieMeyer
If you want to save to the list -1, if you don't want, enter 1 : 1
Save the list to a file
```

I'd like to print it out like this, but what should I do?

Comment: So ... you open the ObjectOutputStream and then close it without trying to write into it. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the general way of writing to file in java.

```
import java.io.FileWriter;   // Import the FileWriter class
try {
      FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter("filename.txt");
      myWriter.write("Write into file here! ");
      myWriter.close();
      System.out.println("Successfully wrote to the file.");
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("An error occurred.");
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To simplify your code and avoid boilerplates I’d recommend you to look towards specific tools and libs working with files.

There is a good article about loading and reading files using Spring:
[Spring Resource](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-classpath-file-access)

For writing content to a file look towards eg “Apache Commons IO” library provides useful helper methods like:

FileUtils.write(new File(“File.txt"), "Content Text", "UTF-8");

In any case investigate these tools and then think about adopting your requirements in them.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
      FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("Book.txt");
      for(int i = 0 ; i < arraylist.size(); i++){
              writer.write(arraylist.get(i).getName();
              writer.write(arraylist.get(i).getAuthor();
      }
      myWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```